# Is it possible to add UI to a node.js application? or is there any UI library for node.js

Tags: node.js, user-interface, raspberry-pi

I am using 'bleno' (https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno, node.js module for implementing Bluetooth low energy peripherals) on my raspberry pi. It works great on terminal but I am looking to make a GUI/Desktop application. I have searched for hours but couldn't find it. there are couple of related threads on SO but none seems to answer this.

Comment: Node.js express and jade or other templating engine work well with html gui.

Comment: @Su4p thanks for the help! but i just realized that i'm looking to create a desktop application on Pi. Probably didn't phrase my question right. anyway.. after more searching, I found node-webkit lib [link](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) which seems to do that.. it can be installed on Linux but not sure about RaspberryPi. need to try.

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking into this - I know this question is old but it's very valid.

Currently I have found:

- [Node-QT](https://github.com/arturadib/node-qt)
- [PiGUI](https://github.com/scottmoss/PiGUI) (Is just a PoC)

But both are over 3 years old. You may have more luck on the [Raspberry Pi stack exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

**UPDATE**
So what I eventually went with in my own application is NodeJS and Socket.IO - and connected an HTML page to the web socket. This gives me the power of HTML5 for my UI. I feel this is the best solution.